# JMockit throwing errors

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I'm trying to mock an interface class using JMockit, following the example in the documentation. However, im getting an error saying that

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matching real methods not found for the following mocks:
>       package.JMockitTest$1#HttpResponse(package.HttpClient client)

```
@Test
public void mockingAnInterface() throws Exception
{

   HttpClient client = new MockUp<HttpClient>() {
      @Mock
      String HttpResponse(HttpClient client)
      {
         return "100";
      }
   }.getMockInstance();

    Weblogic weblogic = new Weblogic();
    Assert.assertEquals(client.HttpResponse("asd"), "100");

}
```

Comment: the error is saying that there is no `String HttpResponse(HttpClient client)` in the `HttpClient` class. What is `HttpClient`? Which method are you trying to mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `String` at line `client.HttpResponse("asd"), "100"` while your mocked method expects a `HttpClient` You need to mock method,

```
@Mock
String HttpResponse(String client)
{
             return "100";
}
```

in your `MockUP` OR

You need to change your call to use `HttpClient` instead of `String`

Comment: ahh yes! these little nitty gritty mistakes. thanks! will accept your answer once its avaliable